# How to compare all possible group combinations with EMMEANS in SPSS?

Tags: spss

Suppose you have a 2x2 design and you're testing differences between those 4 groups using ANOVA in SPSS.
This is a graph of your data:

[image]

After performing ANOVA, there are 6 possible pairwise comparisons between groups that we can perform. These are:

A - C

B - D

A - D

B - C

A - B

C - D

If I want to perform pairwise comparisons, I would usually use this script after the `UNIANOVA` command:

```
/EMMEANS=TABLES(Var1*Var2) COMPARE (Var1) ADJ(LSD)
/EMMEANS=TABLES(Var1*Var2) COMPARE (Var2) ADJ(LSD)
```

However, after running this script, the output only contains 4 of the 6 possible comparisons - there are two pairwise comparisons that are missing, and those are:

A - B

C - D

How can I calculate those comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMMEANS in UNIANOVA does not provide all pairwise comparisons among the cells in an interaction like this. There are some other procedures, such as GENLIN, that do offer these, but use large-sample chi-square statistics rather than t or F statistics. In UNIANOVA, you can get these using the LMATRIX subcommand, or you can use some trickery with EMMEANS.

For the trickery with EMMEANS, create a single factor with four levels that index the 2x2 layout of cells, then handle that as a one-way model. The main effect for that is the same as the overall 3 degree of freedom model for the 2x2 layout, and of course EMMEANS with COMPARE works fine on that.

Without creating a new variable, you can use LMATRIX with:

```
 /LMATRIX "(1,1) - (2,2)" var1 1 -1 var2 1 -1 var1*var2 1 0 0 -1
 /LMATRIX "(1,2) - (2,1)" var1 1 -1 var1 -1 1 var1*var2 0 1 -1 0
```

The quoted pieces are labels, indicating the cells in the 2x2 design being compared.

Another trick you can use to make specifying the LMATRIX simpler, but without creating a new variable, is to specify the DESIGN with just the interaction term and suppress the intercept. That makes the parameter estimates just the four cell means:

```
UNIANOVA Y BY var1 var2
/INTERCEPT=EXCLUDE
/DESIGN var1*var1
/LMATRIX "(1,1) - (2,2)" var1*var2 1 0 0 -1
/LMATRIX "(1,2) - (2,1)" var1*var1 0 1 -1 0.
```

In this case the one effect shown in the ANOVA table is a 4 df effect testing all means against 0, so it's not of interest, but the comparisons you want are easily obtained. Note that this trick only works with procedures that don't reparameterize to full rank.